# How to use Virtual Box with a Disk image created with Norton Ghost?

Tags: windows, ubuntu, virtualbox, virtual-machine, norton-ghost

I was given a file with "sv2i" extension and a couple of "v2i" files. According to my search, it is a disk image created with Norton Ghost. I converted the sv2i file to a vmdk file, which apparently is one type that virtual box understand. I made this by using VMWare VCenter Converter Standalone.

Until this point, everything went ok. But when I created the virtual machine with Windows XP (which is apparently the OS used by the disk image owner) using the vmdk file as hard disk for the machine, it appeared the following message:

```
*Windows failed to start. A recent hardware or software change might be the cause To fix the problem:
    Insert your Windows installation disc and restart your computer.
    Choose your language settings, and then click "Next."
    Click "Repair your computer."
If you do not have this disc, contact your system administrator or computer manufacturer for assistance.
Status: 0xc0000225
Info: The boot selection failed because a required device is inaccessible.*
```

The problem is that, I don't have an iso of the Windows Version into that disk image, so I don't know what else I could do.

The host OS is Ubuntu 12.04.

**UPDATE**

I've been updated and the correct OS is Windows 7 Professional 64 bits. I made some changes in the configuration=> Enable IO APIC, remove the SATA controller and use IDE PIIX4 without host I/O cache and attach vmdk to IDE. Now what I have is the blue screen of death. But at least, when I tried to repair Windows from the DVD, it recognizes the previous windows installation (From the vmdk)

The configuration changes were made thanks this helpful post 
http://blog.csanchez.org/2011/08/01/migrating-windows-7-from-vmware-fusion-to-virtualbox/

Answer (score 0):

Do I understand it right that your virtual machine is running Windows? If so, then there is probably no (legal) way around it, and possibly even no illegal one.

Windows software is not FOSS (Free Open Source Software); it is licensed under restrictive and binding agreements for use on a specific machine. Once it is by any means transferred onto  different hardware, it is capable of detecting the new environment under which it is called to operate, and will refuse to do so unless license is transferred (under, once again, binding terms) to the new environment. Ownership of the installation disk is often taken as necessary (but not sufficient) proof of legal ownership.

The above even applies for installation of Windows software onto a VM on a host operating legally under Microsoft software, let alone on a different pc running FOSS Operating System.

Comment: I am new at virtual machines but I've been searching information about this for a while and I can say many people seem to use VM in this way. I mean, they have a  PC running Ubuntu and another with Windows. And they made a back-up image from their Windows and then run a virtual machine on Ubuntu so they can have the two OS in the same PC. However, I don't really know the legal implications of this